# How to test php mail() function locally on Homestead

Tags: php, email, homestead

I'm very new to php and am trying to test the mail() function locally. I'm using Homestead/Laravel as a local server. My php.ini file only has one line, where I turn debugging on. Any Homestead/Laravel people out there know how to edit my files so that I can test email locally? Note: I added echo in front of the mail funciton to see if it was working at all.

```
<?php
$emailTo = "test@gmail.com";
$subject = "Testing out PHP";
$body = "Huzzah";
$headers = "From: test@test.co.uk";

echo mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);    
?>
```

Comment: Yes, same. It is not clear if it should work or should not.

Comment: Ok. I tried homestead and it did not work, I tried AWS hosted account and it worked. Thus I think it should not send emails from homestead. I don't know if it can be fixed, though.

Answer (score 6):

Use:

- the log driver

  > In `project/config/mail.php`, set the mail driver to `log`:
  >
  > ```
  > 'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'log'),
  > ```
  >
  > then check your log files for the emails: `project/storage/logs/*.log`
- a universal to-address (and send everything to yourself)
- a dummy mailbox

Check this link for more information: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#mail-and-local-development

Comment: Thanks so much! I actually don't think I was clear with my question. The problem I'm experiencing is that these emails aren't sending at all. I'm find having them send out locally, but currently they will not send at all.

Comment: It's better to put this in the `.env` file instead of the `config/mail.php`.

Answer (score 3):

There's even more useful thing - the [Mailhog](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#configuring-mailhog).

The documentation says:

> Mailhog allows you to easily catch your outgoing email and examine it
>   without actually sending the mail to its recipients. To get started,
>   update your .env file to use the following mail settings:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

> Once Mailhog has been configured, you may access the Mailhog dashboard
>   at http://localhost:8025.

Really nice thing in my opinion.

Comment: Correct answer !